# Are all ideals $I$ in the ring of smooth functions on a compact manifold M equal to a set of smooth functions that vanish in $Z \subset M$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras

Since $M$ is compact, we know that maximal ideals are $m_x$, the set of functions vanishing in $ x \in M$. Thus by Zorn's Lemma we also have that $I$ must sit inside such a $m_x$ for some $x \in M$.

It seems logical that $ I$ should be a $m_Z$ where $Z$ is the intersection of kernels over all functions from $I$. The set $Z$ is non-empty as a consequence of Zorn's Lemma.

Then clearly by definition of $Z$ we have $ I \subset m_Z$. I just have trouble seeing that $ M_Z \subset I $. Any ideas?

Comment: As a counterexample take the ideal of all functions vanishing to order $\ge 2$ in a point.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this is an old question, but it was never answered here. So I'll take a crack at it: no, not every ideal is of the form $\frak{m}\!$$_Z$.

Let $M$ be a compact Hausdorff manifold. Then (1) every ideal is contained in some $\frak{m}\!$$_x$, and (2) there are ideals strictly contained in a unique $\frak{m}\!$$_x$.

$\textbf{Proof (1):}$ Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $\mathcal{C}$, the smooth $\mathbb{R}$ valued functions on $M$. Define $\mathcal{Z}[f]:=\{x\in M|f(x)=0\}$, and suppose that  $\bigcap_{f\in I}\mathcal{Z}[f]=\emptyset$. Then $M=\bigcup_{f\in I}\mathcal{Z}[f]^c$ and because $M$ is compact there is some finite collection of functions $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $M=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathcal{Z}[f_i]^c$. But that would mean that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathcal{Z}[f_i]=\emptyset$, so $\sum_{i=1}^nf^2_i\in I$ would be a unit, so $I=\mathcal{C}$. Then it must be that, $\exists x\in\bigcap_{f\in I}\mathcal{Z}[f]$ and so $I\subseteq \frak{m}\!$$_x$.
So, if $I$ is maximal then we have that $I=\frak{m}\!$$_x$.

$\textbf{Proof (2):}$ If we define $\frak{o}\!$$_x:=\{f\in\mathcal{C}|f \text{ vanishes on a neighborhood of }x\}$, then this is an ideal of $\mathcal{C}$. Clearly $\frak{o}\!$$_x\subsetneq\frak{m}\!$$_x$, but if we take $y\neq x$ there must be a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $y\notin\overline U$ because $M$ is Hausdorff. Because compact and Hausdorff implies Tikhonov, we know that there must be $f\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $U\subseteq\mathcal{Z}[f]$ and $f(y)=1$. Then we may conclude that $\frak{o}\!$$_x\not\subseteq\frak{m}\!$$_y$.

Answer (score 2):

The compactness of $M$ does not guarantee that every maximal ideal is principal without additional assumptions. If $M$ has positive dimension then it contains infinitely many points and therefore there are always maximal nonprincipal ideals.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: @abx, the relation is that the OP's question is based on an incorrect premise as I pointed out.

Comment: There is no mention of principal ideals in the OP question.

Comment: @abx, the set of functions vanishing at a point $x\in M$ is by definition a principal ideal in the ring of functions. However, there are other maximal ones.

Comment: You have a strange definition of a principal ideal! Look at "principal ideal" in Wikipedia.

Comment: @abx at any rate it is *not* true that every maximal ideal is the ideal of functions vanishing at a point. This usage of the term principal ideal can be found for instance in *Hewitt, Edwin Rings of real-valued continuous functions. I. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.  64,  (1948), 45–99* where NONprincipal ideals called hyper-real ideals were first exploited.

Comment: @MikhailKatz this is really old, but the claim that any maximal ideal is the ideal of functions vanishing at a point is true for compact $M$. See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3871/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-continuous-real-valued-functions-on-r

Comment: @M10687 I am not sure what happened here: either I did not notice that the functions need to be continuous or I overlooked that the manifold is compact, I don't remember.