# What are the maximal ideals in $C(0,1)$ apart from $M_c = \{f\in C(0,1) | f(c)=0\}$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I have studied about maximal ideals in $C[0,1]$ . They are precisely of the form $$\{f\in C[0,1] | f(c)=0\} \text{ for } c\in [0,1].$$

If we replace $[0,1]$ by $(0,1)$ and then look at $C(0,1)$, then obviously  $M_c = \{f\in C(0,1) | f(c)=0\}$ are maximal ideals in $C(0,1)$ , $\forall c \in (0,1)$ , but since we do not have the compactness of $[0,1]$ anymore, I guess there are some other maximal ideals as well.

I am trying to solve the problem by first giving an existential argument and then by showing an explicit maximal ideal other that of the form $M_c$ for some $c \in (0,1)$ .

Comment: Do you want $C((0,1))$, i.e. all the continous functions (possibly unbounded), or $C_b((0,1))$ (only the bounded continuous ones)?

Comment: I would like to know about both, but my question is precisely intended for all the continuous functions on $(0,1)$ that is also taking the unbounded ones into account!

Comment: For bounded functions this seems to be directly linked to the Stone-Cech compactification. And you could probably find a bit more in the classical text Gillman, Jerison: *Rings of Continuous Functions*. (I guess somebody who know more about this will post a more detailed answer soon.) However, I am not sure whether this is too helpful, since Stone-Cech compactification of $(0,1)$ seems like a quite complicated object.

Comment: In the case of $C_b(X)$ for non-compact Hausdorff $X$, the Gelfand-Naimark theorem tells us that this must be isomorphic to $C_b(Y)$, where $Y$ is the compact space of all maximal ideals (equivalently - continuous characters). It turns out that $Y$ is precisely the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Construction_using_C*-algebras) of $X$, which is notoriously difficult to give explicitely even for simple spaces.

Comment: For reasonnable topological spaces (*real-compact*) the maximal ideals of $C(X)$ are the kernels of evaluations. I don't have references at hand, but everything should be in Engelking.

Comment: Since $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic, this question might be worth looking at: [Maximal ideals in the ring of continuous real-valued functions on R](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3871).

Comment: @AlexM., [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298870/what-are-the-maximal-ideals-in-c0-1-apart-from-m-c-f-in-c0-1-fc-0/378412#comment743602_298870), according to [@‍EricWofsey](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3876/2383) (who cites Johnstone's "Stone spaces" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=698074))), the maximal ideals in $C(X)$ and $C_b(X)$ are the same.

Comment: The difference between the bounded and unbounded case would provide a more exciting question, I'd think.

Answer (score 5):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic, you can look at maximal ideal in $C(\mathbb R)$.

There is the idea form Dummit and Foote *Abstract Algebra*, page 259 Ex 34.

Let $I\subset C(\mathbb R)$ be the set of all continuous functions with compact support. It can be shown that $I$ is an ideal. Let $M$ be a maximal ideal containing $I$. Then $M\neq M_{c}$ for any $c\in \mathbb R$. For suppose $M=M_{c}$, and let $r=|c|+1$. There is a function $f\in C(\mathbb R)$, such that $f(x)>0$ when $x\in (-|c|,|c|)$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x>r$ or $x<-r$. Then $f\in I$ but $f\notin M_{c}$.

Comment: This is one of those occasions when you have the sinking feeling that Zorn's lemma isn't such a great idea.

Comment: Of course *the* maximal ideal here is really *a* maximal ideal, right, or is there only one? \\ Notice that this point of view was already [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298870/what-are-the-maximal-ideals-in-c0-1-apart-from-m-c-f-in-c0-1-fc-0#comment743626_298870) by @MartinSleziak, who linked to https://mathoverflow.net/q/3871, although this particular answer does not seem to appear there.

Comment: Specifically, this construction is mentioned by @AntonGeraschenko in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3871/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-continuous-real-valued-functions-on-r#comment3966_3871).

Comment: @LSpice But notice that [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3876) there shows that maximal ideals correspond to points of $\beta\mathbb R$.  So if $x\in\beta\mathbb R \setminus\mathbb R$ then $f(x)=0$ for any $f\in I$, and so $M_x$ contains $I$.  Thus there are many, many choices for $M$.

Comment: @MatthewDaws, [indeed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298870/what-are-the-maximal-ideals-in-c0-1-apart-from-m-c-f-in-c0-1-fc-0/378412#comment960308_378412), thanks.  Your 'but' suggests disagreement, but I meant to argue *against* the terminology "the maximal ideal containing $I$", not *for* it.  (Anyway, @‍AlexM. has now edited out that terminology, so I would delete [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298870/what-are-the-maximal-ideals-in-c0-1-apart-from-m-c-f-in-c0-1-fc-0/378412#comment960272_378412) except that I think that the other half of it might still be worthwhile.)